# Bubble sort dynamically created struct array in c

Tags: c, sockets, client

Really new here so sorry for any further mistakes..
I've got some new school project (Learning C), what I must to is to connect to the server
using sockets than download all code lines from the server.
After that I need to sort the lines so they be in order, where I got is on the sort.. well I already downloaded the code lines saved them in struct array but now my bubble sort shows some error to me and I don't know what's the problem.. thx for any help.

```
typedef struct DATA{

    char* buf;
}DATA;
//  this fucntion creates a socket.
void sort_array(DATA *to_sort, int len){

    int i, j;
    char tmp[1024] = "";

    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++){
            if (strcmp(to_sort[j].buf, to_sort[j + 1].buf) < 0){
                strcpy(tmp, to_sort[j + 1].buf);
                strcpy(to_sort[j + 1].buf, to_sort[j].buf);
                strcpy(to_sort[j].buf, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){

    WSADATA info;
    int error, s,j;
    int sendError, recvError;
    char buffer[1024] = "100",readbuf[1024] = "";
    char recvbuf[1024] = "";
    int numberLines, i, temp, convert;
    char converted_num[1024] = "";
    char *sub;
    struct sockaddr_in ClientService;
    FILE *fp = fopen("stored_data.txt", "w");
    FILE *ofp = fopen("final_result.txt", "w");
    DATA *to_sort = NULL;

    error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &info);
    //check if error occurred while configuring.
    if (error != 0){
        printf("WSAstartup failed with error: %d\n", error);
        exit(1);
    }
    s = socket_creation(fp);

    // configuration of the socket.
    ClientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ClientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("54.209.143.42");
    ClientService.sin_port = htons(6714);
    connection(s, ClientService, fp); // function connecting to the server.

    error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &info);

    // send '100' login command to server.
    strcpy(buffer, "100");
    sendError = send_to_serv(buffer, s);

    // receiving respond  from the server.
    recvError = recv_from_serv(s, &numberLines, fp,buffer);

    // send '400' get number lines command to server.
    strcpy(buffer, "400");
    sendError = send_to_serv(buffer, s);

    // receiving respond from the server.
    recvError = recv_from_serv(s, &numberLines, fp,buffer);

    printf("\nNumber of Lines are: %d\n", numberLines);
    temp = numberLines; // number of all lines received.

    /* allocate mmoery for struct array to store the data from server */
    to_sort = (DATA*)malloc(sizeof(DATA)* temp);

    // getting the lines from the server.
    for (i = 0; i < temp; i++){
        j = 0;
        convert = 5000001 + i; // creating number of line wanted.
        _itoa(convert, converted_num, 10); // converting the int to a string (wanted line).
        sendError = send_to_serv(converted_num, s); // sending the server request of line wanted.
        recv_from_serv(s, &numberLines, fp, buffer); // receive the line wanted.
        sub = substring(buffer, 0, 3);

        // checks if the server returned '502 OK' or '501 REJECT'
        if (strcmp(sub, "502") != 0){
            to_sort[j].buf = buffer;
            j++;
        }
    }
    sort_array(to_sort, temp); // sorting the struct array.

    // printing the final result.

    // clean memoery.
    free(to_sort);
    fclose(fp);
    system("PAUSE>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should have cut away all the irrelevant (socket and loading) code, and made a program that *only* contains the code you have problems with, i.e. the sorting. Also, why not use `qsort()`?

Comment: Oh, first off i'm sorry. didn't know that.. second of i'm not really well my teacher asked me not to do that with qsort()

Comment: You should tell us what error you do get, and cut off all irrelevant code.

Comment: well I think I cut off now all irrelevant code the error that I'n getting is from the sort_array function. and it's
 `Unhandled exception at 0x5EEB4282 (msvcr120d.dll) in C Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.` @Theolodis @unwind

Comment: to_sort[j].buf = buffer;
pointer to same buffer for all pointers? IMHO needs to be initialized and copied. 2) j++ only in condition. If 502 then don't stop looping. 3) free(to_sort) array of char arrays. Then free all arrays, and after that to_sort itself.

Comment: 4) When sorting strings don't do strcpy. Move only pointers. That is faster and easier.

Comment: Uhm it is to the same buffer because I receive a lot of data from the server through that buffer and it changed :O 502 returned from server means I didn't receive any data so I don't want to move further in the array.. I'm sure I understand you correctly :X @IvanIvanov

Answer (score 0):

```
void bsort(char **data, size_t size) {
    size_t i, j;
    char *tmp = NULL;

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (strcmp(data[j-1], data[j]) > 0) {
                tmp = data[j-1];
                data[j-1] = data[j];
                data[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code do sort. I checked))) Need more time. Mean try this code, if not work then go further and check error again.

```
to_sort[j] = (char*) malloc(1024);
memcpy(to_sort[j].buf, buffer, 1024);
j++;
```

I read data until I get full buffer. Don't try to check 502 every time while data is coming. Only once, after got reply. After that you stream response until the end.

```
#define REPLY 1024
do {
    bytes_read = recv(sock, server_reply, REPLY, 0);
    if (bytes_read == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        perror("error recieving data");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (bytes_read > 0) {
        to_sort[j] = (char*) malloc(1024);
        memcpy(to_sort[j].buf, server_reply, 1024);
        j++;
    }
} while (bytes_read == REPLY);
```

UPD

```
void bsort(DATA *data, size_t size) {
    size_t i, j;
    DATA tmp;

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (strcmp(data[j-1].buf, data[j].buf) > 0) {
                tmp = data[j-1];
                data[j-1] = data[j];
                data[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPD2

```
//1) Simpliest way
//pointer to array
DATA *s = NULL;
//size of array
size_t array_size = 50;

//create array of DATA elements
s = (DATA *) malloc(sizeof(DATA) * array_size);
//now you have array of DATA. But each element contains uninitialized pointer
//of type char

//set each pointer to proper address on heap
//each element now can handle string length 1023
//note here all strings have same size
for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    s[i].buf = (char*) malloc(1024);
}
```

and free

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    free(s[i].buf);
}
free(s);
```

with sort

```
DATA *s = NULL;
size_t array_size = 5;
size_t i;

s = (DATA *) malloc(sizeof(DATA) * array_size);

for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    s[i].buf = (char*) malloc(1024);
}

strcpy(s[0].buf, "AAAAA");
strcpy(s[1].buf, "CCCCC");
strcpy(s[2].buf, "XXXXX");
strcpy(s[3].buf, "AAAAA");
strcpy(s[4].buf, "BBBBB");

bsort(s, 5);

for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", s[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    free(s[i].buf);
}
free(s);
```

UPD3 more sophisticated way to allocate memory, but much faster

```
DATA *s = NULL;
size_t array_size = 5;
size_t item_size = 1024;
size_t i;

s = (DATA *) malloc(sizeof(DATA) * array_size + array_size * item_size);
s[0].buf = (char*) (s + array_size);
for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    s[i].buf = s[0].buf + i * item_size;
}

strcpy(s[0].buf, "AAAAA");
strcpy(s[1].buf, "CCCCC");
strcpy(s[2].buf, "XXXXX");
strcpy(s[3].buf, "AAAAA");
strcpy(s[4].buf, "BBBBB");

bsort(s, 5);

for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", s[i]);
}

free(s);
```

Comment: Look, i'm not trying to bubble sort an string array, I'm trying to bubble sort and `struct` so.. :S thank you anyways :)

Comment: Your struct contains only one field, so in c it the same pointer. You just add alias to it.

Comment: you're sort didn't work for me either.. I'm confused now , How can i create dynamically struct array 1 dimension tho `sizeof temp` fields.